# Update all the data in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have the following data in my mongo database.

```
{
  "FirstName": "Sunil",
  "LastName": "Jamkatel"
}
```

I would like to add fullname to all the documents in the database such that it takes the firstname and lastname from a document and adds them up like:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Sunil",
  "LastName": "Jamkatel",
  "FullName": "Sunil Jamkatel"
}
```

Please let me know the ways to do it using mongoosejs.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a [virtual property](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) to compute `FullName` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use a update with `multi` option set to `true`. The statement may look like:

```
YourModel.update(
  {},  
  {
    $set: {
      "FullName": "Sunil Jamkatel"
    }
  },
  {
    multi: true
  }
);
```

Comment: I would like to do this to all the data in the database. I'm adding firstname and lastname. !

Comment: You said you want to add fullname field in the question?

Comment: Is there anyway we could do that? Sorry I was not clear earlier.

Comment: So you can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/6876291